# Is SSH keypair like this enough to log in to SSH?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh

For instance, I have something very similar to this below left from another dev in a "keys.pub" file, he claims I should be able to login using only this without pass/username to system...he also says he never tried it (this below is from cat command...):

"root:
root:
root:ssh-rsa exampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeenoO3k4neuw+AUic5QScN/qLFJwsqCP2pc7ySR2qaVOp568X2Wx381COgUmUqy0mOXEU2/Mh64sQIPBzVwxyALHx0J/88sWmh/wqjI7x7BfdioU717X9CKysaD4Rq+9eTMxspkNBYC5Thhgym9TzOMFYMjeVhkR86j9bjmBM03QlUFnSklPypTvGEEcxXPTOHeSqdILAheKqjqF4TbvIzP9N0JA6aPgdrCWvZ9Mh7GlUUPCnOXmmSAIrNFubKQeeZQRFre6hKqBDRTis4cCfRLmb/eFdg+31QMV6ptY3T5/Ib+VCTUM//ewaXWfvXSYmF dev@testing"

So dev@testing is SSH user, the rest is password and I should put this .pub file somewhere inn Putty, correct? thanks!

Comment: Anyway, I got it, thanks!

Comment: Convert to a pfk in puttygen, then use.

Comment: This is not really about programming or programming tools - probably belongs to superuser or serverfault

Comment: @JNevill: OK but is this enough? Do I need privatte key since this is .pub? Anyway I will try just in case...

Comment: You are correct. Generally what happens is the client generates a keypair (public and private). Private key is retained by the client (depending on the client this is stored in differently places, a pfk for putty in windows). The public key is shared with the server. It will go in the server user's `.ssh` folder in the `authorized_keys` file. Both the `.ssh` directory and the file have to have the correct permissions (using chmod to correct). Then you should be good to go. It can be a bit of a pain the first time around.

Comment: Server is Debian 9.3, can I (having root access) look inside th .ssh folder of the server and get the private key from there or is it only stored by the whoever client had connected first?

Answer (score 0):

`dev@testing` is not necessarily the user, that is likely the email given when creating the keys, or is tied to the user creating the key.

What you have there looks to be the public key only. This is what you put on the server to use it to login. But what you will need is the private key, which is usually kept seperate and often password protected.

Comment: OK, I'll have to ask about that then since having root to server + pub doesn't seem enough...